# How can I take the variable from the parent class constructor and use it in the child class?

Tags: python, class

I have been working on classes and objects in a budgeter project. I am extremely confused on how to take the variable that I got from the constructor in the parent class and use it in the child class.

This might look like a duplicate, but I am not able to understand the answers on the other posts. Please try to explain as simply as you can without any "foreign" terms as I am new to coding.

The main issues I got were:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not int
```

And here's my code:

```
class budget:
    def __init__(self, money):
        self.money = money

class food(budget):
    def __init__(self, money):
        money = super(budget).__init__(2)
    def show(self):
        print('hi')

money = 50
a = food(money)
a.show()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It would do exactly what you want to do if you didn't have any `__init__` method in your `food` class. That's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: Ohh. I see. So I just made a silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Option 1 ---> with your example you dint need an __init__
class budget:
    def __init__(self, money):
        self.money = money

class food(budget):
    def show(self):
        print('hi')
money = 50
a = food(money)
a.show()


#Option 2 if you still need to override the init
class budget:
    def __init__(self, money):
        print('here')
        self.money = money

class food(budget):
    def __init__(self, money):
        super().__init__(money)
    def show(self):
        print('hi')

money = 50
a = food(money)
a.show()
```

** Also Note: you cant pass in a argument that then becomes a variable